# Does @Html.Action() and @Html.RenderAction() make another call to the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This has been bothering me since the first time I saw these methods in the view and I couldn't find any answer on the net.

So if I put this code inside my view

```
<div id="categories">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
</div>
```

Does that mean that we are making another call to the server after the view is rendered ?

And If not, how does it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: No that code is ran while the razor is being parsed when the server is generating the page to send to the client. You can set break points on it to check if you would like.

Comment: adding to all the learned commentary, http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The view is being generated in it's entirety within the same request.  It just means you are rendering the result of an action you've defined in one of your controllers into the current view.